Is it possible to use the Spotify API to display what I'm currently listening to as part of my website?
I want to know if it is possible for me to have a banner on my personal website that says "I am currently listening to : [insert track]" where [insert track] is sourced from the Spotify dev API. I know that the Spotify API has an endpoint called currently_playing, but after investigating I found out it uses the OAuth_2 flow and, though maybe I'm wrong, I think that means that anytime you want to call and display api information you have to have the person viewing the website log into THEIR account, so it will display THEIR info, not mine, which defeats the whole point (the point is to broadcast to everyone what I am listening to). Is there any way around this, or even better, am I misunderstanding OAuth_2? It's kind of a simple concept so I would really love it if I could bring it together.
I tried this:
async function fetchCurrentlyPlaying(token) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing", {
        method: 'GET', 
        headers: {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token}
      });
      if (response.data && response.data.item) {
        const { name, artists, album, external_urls } = response.data.item;
        return response.status(200).json({
          name,
          artists: artists.map((artist) => artist.name),
          album: album.name,
          image: album.images[0]?.url,
          url: external_urls.spotify,
        });
      } else {
        return response.status(204).json({ message: 'No song is currently playing.' });
      }
    }catch(error){
      console.error(error);
      return ({ error: 'Error fetching currently playing track' });
    }
  }

where token is a token I generate using client credential flow (I believe), however it gave me back:
{
  "error" : {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Invalid username"
  }
}

Which is why I started digging and found out about OAuth_2 (which I previously skipped over I think)

Hey there ! I saw your question and wanted to checkout why it’s downvoted (there’s litteraly no reason so don’t bother with this). About your issue, try to check the request content and eventual issues with permissions. I think you already saw it but there’s this API documentation here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-the-users-currently-playing-track
